# Calling 3rd party webservice with custom authentication - unable to set BinarysecurityToken encoding

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap-client, ws-security

I've got a problem with calling 3rd party soap service which requires custom security header.
Service requires:
- signature token
- UserNameToken with password digest

Example XML Request provided that I need to produce is:

```
    <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss- wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss- wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-6">
      <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username- token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">Cf2oC6oKxHPSkuucpRVCBe6zvls=</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap- message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">FEKAmN+tzmkGPRPF6mlSOw==</wsse:Nonce>
      <wsu:Created>2013-10-30T07:59:00.822Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 2 0 04 01-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis - open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509- AC67D3CC57893B4EEE13831199408014">

    </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    <ds:Signature Id="SIG-5" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
          <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="br soapenv xsd xsd1" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa- sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#id-4">
          <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="br xsd xsd1" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transform>
          </ds:Transforms >
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2 0 0 0/0 9/xmldsig#sha1"/>
          <ds:DigestValue>yyV5kSNl7vbdaytDXkyFh2pZyVs=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>
        cVdChX0SOzdfPhtKehPwvKzYnWDKnF0rlc7h5AbInj EB3cmK+73LpV5SM9VzhtGVYuO7 KSw9TnEY
        2al0x2 7VJW0NFeqCcPpllfSsUa9Ajbfy5TUbiEfAEQgJO+LDQ2pMVcj D6RlyDqAewd+Qc19PxC9G vo5kYJSqgtz5Prtt8AU=
      </ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-AC67D3CC57893B4EEE13831199408015">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-AC67D3CC57893B4EEE13831199408016">
          <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-AC67D3CC57893B4EEE13831199408014" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile- 1.0#X509v3"/>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
```

I removed binary security token body to shorten the code.

Based on this blog post:  http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication I was able to get the UsernameToken with password digest which is not supported in .net.


I'm awaare that I need to create custom binding and this is how I do it:

```
 var security = TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
            security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
            security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;

            var encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(M

essageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);

        var transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        transport.RequireClientCertificate = true;

        X509SecurityTokenParameters tokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters() ;
        tokenParameters.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;
        tokenParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;            
        security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEndorsing.Add(tokenParameters);
        security.IncludeTimestamp = true;

        Binding wsHttpBinding = new CustomBinding(security, encoding, transport);
```

Then by creating client I do:

```
client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Remove(typeof(System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials));
                client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomCredentials());

                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "USERNAME";
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PASSWORD";

                client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "THUMBPRINT HERE");
                client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.CertificateAuthority, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "THUMBPRINT HERE");
```

My request that is generated then is:

```
<s:Header>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo4wSObzORadLnfUo7CveHxIAAAAAgiA2egk73keuG3wU7Bguf0B05rx1GLZNpyEK0K10wwkACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2015-07-15T04:08:53.219Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2015-07-15T04:13:53.219Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-537f9cc8-0820-48ed-80d0-10f2865ae4ba-1" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <o:Username>repl_swdr_2160_2</o:Username>
        <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">/BNv+zkamYJsNDqjieV3dQMVDsU=</o:Password>
        <o:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">YmNjMWQ4ZTYtNmJlMi00OTYzLWE4NmYtZmM4MTFkMTBlZGZl</o:Nonce>
        <u:Created>2015-07-15T04:08:53.431Z</u:Created>
      </o:UsernameToken>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-537f9cc8-0820-48ed-80d0-10f2865ae4ba-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">TOKEN BODY HERE</BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#_0">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>+XE6oHkNmMy2CeOE39GkwfyG0J0=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>SIGNATURE VALUE HERE</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference URI="#uuid-537f9cc8-0820-48ed-80d0-10f2865ae4ba-2"/>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
```

The error that I get is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <Exception>
          org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed
          at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processMessage(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
          Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An invalid security token was provided (A bad EncodingType attribute was specified "")
          at org.apache.ws.security.message.token.BinarySecurity.&lt;init>(Unknown Source)
         at org.apache.ws.security.message.token.X509Security.&lt;init>(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.processor.BinarySecurityTokenProcessor.createSecurityToken(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.processor.BinarySecurityTokenProcessor.handleToken(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(Unknown Source)
          ... 25 more
        </Exception>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So it looks like the EncodingType attribute is missing in BinarySecurityToken, but I cannot figure out why?

When I manually set this encoding in Fiddler and repost my request the error I get is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <Exception>
          org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed
          at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processMessage(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
          Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An invalid security token was provided (Bad ValueType "")
          at org.apache.ws.security.str.BSPEnforcer.checkBinarySecurityBSPCompliance(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.str.SignatureSTRParser.processPreviousResult(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.str.SignatureSTRParser.parseSecurityTokenReference(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(Unknown Source)
          ... 25 more
        </Exception>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Would you be able to help me figure out how to make the **EncodingType be added to the BinarySecurityToken?**
Any further help would also be highly appriciated.